# MVC: Adding new model instance from within view that uses different model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently started using MVC, and as a test project I am creating a simple "blog". I have got a basic structure in place where the main page displays all the posts and when you click on it it will go into the detail page.

[image: Structure]

Now I am trying to add `comments` (Comment.cs)to my posts from within the `Home/Details` view, which basically requires me to have 2 models in 1 view. Model 1 is the `Post` model and Model 2 is the `Comment` model;

- Post.cs is used to get the details of the post
- Comment.cs is used to add a comment to the post

This is the code for my `Home/details` view:

```
@model MVCPortfolio.Models.Post

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>@Model.Title - @Model.Author</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Posted on @Model.Date.ToShortDateString()</legend>
    <div class="content">
         @Model.Content
    </div>
</fieldset>
    <div class="comments">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var c in Model.Comments)
            {
            <li>
                @c.Content - @c.Author
            </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="newcomment">
@*  @Html.EditorFor(model => model) *@
</div>

<p>
@* 
    @Html.ActionLink("New Comment", "Comment", new { id = Model.PostId }) 
*@
    |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

And this is my home controller, from within which I want to add comments.

```
    private PortfolioEntities db = new PortfolioEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var posts = (from p in db.Posts
                     orderby p.Date
                     select p);

        return View(posts);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var post = (from p in db.Posts
                    where p.PostId == id
                    select p).Single();

        return View(post);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }

        return View(comment);
    }
}
```

But what I don't understand is how to add the `comment` to the `post`, I can easily add a new `post` ([see my Create.cshtml view](http://pastebin.com/ViyhWTXJ)), but I cannot figure out how to add a `comment` from within the `post` detail view.

Thank you for your time,
Thomas

Comment: What is the issue?  This all looks fine.

Comment: Are you not looking for a ViewModel class that contains both your required models?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post with hopefully a better question: The issue is that I cannot figure out how to add a `comment` from within the `post` detail view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of the clarifications, I think you should create a [partial view](http://www.devcurry.com/2012/04/partial-views-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html) for that.

In your view, subsitute

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Comment", "Comment", new { id = Model.PostId })
```

with a call to render a partial view

```
@Html.Partial("_Comment")
```

Your partial view should handle the UI for adding a `Comment`, ending with a call to your `Comment` action method in your `PostController`

Comment: The view shows that `Comments` is a collection on the `Model`.  So, I don't think a view model helps in this instance.

Comment: Oops you are right...I shall delete that option then, thanks!

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear; I want to add a `Comment` (Comment.cs) from within the (Home/Details) view (which uses the `Post` model (Post.cs)). In my view you can see that I can manage to get all the comments from a model but I do not know how to add one

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing what you suggest but I am getting this error on the @Html.Partiel("_Comment"): `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Post_82B3A31844779BDB10E3FD1AC7F6F175455ACCDEE6EFFCDF662634B02654BDF4', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCPortfolio.Models.Comment'.`

Comment: Please check your references and your `using` statements